# Is my wheel broken?

Tags: wheels, maintenance, puncture

[image]

The other day my inner tube suffered a blow out and I'm wondering if this is the cause

One side of the joint in the wheel seems to have come out of alignment and now there is a sharp bit sticking out.

I would have thought that the tyre would have protected the tube, but maybe it hit it just right.

If the wheel is broken, is it something that can be fixed, or should I be looking at new wheels?

Comment: That "crack" is where the ends of the tubing used to make the wheel come together.  It does not indicate a failure, per se.  The one edge is displaced slightly, but, as you say, the tire should protect the tube from being damaged by it.  The thing to check is whether the hole in the tube corresponds with the split in the rim.  If it does then probably the rim/wheel should be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

That does look like a rather poorly manufactured rim. As Daniel R Hicks commented, the big sticking-out corner shouldn't be able to puncture the tube because the tyre is in between, however there also seems to be a bit of a sharp edge further inwards and that might indeed damage the tube. I would cover this part with duct tape and look to replace the rim at the next good opportunity.

That said: tubes blow out for all kinds of reasons, so don't jump to conclusions too quick here. Certainly worth checking whether the puncture is actually at the corresponding place, but I guess you've already done that.

Comment: Also, when they get a puncture, they can try and find exactly where, in relation to the wheel, the tube is punctured. This way they can see whether it was near the dodgy bit.